# How to store Terraform state in SVN?

Tags: terraform

Does Terraform allow storing the state file in SVN? If this is not directly supported by Terraform, do any third party/ open source options exist?

Comment: svn and terraform are a very unusual mix, to the point where I've never encountered anyone doing that before. You can store your state file anywhere you want, but remote state with online storage like S3 or Azure Storage are preferred to direct version control.

Answer (score 0):

When using Terraform it's *not* typical to store the Terraform state in the same version control repository as the configuration that drives it, because the expected workflow to use version control with Terraform is to review and commit the proposed changes first, and only *then* apply the changes to your real infrastructure from your main branch.

To understand why it might help to think about the relationship between an application's main code and its database. We don't typically store the main database for a web application in the version control repository along with the code, because the way we interact with the two are different: many developers can be concurrently working on and proposing changes to the application source code, and our version control system is often able to merge together those separate proposals to reduce collisions, but for the application's central database it's more common to use locks so that two writers don't try to change the same data (or interconnected data) at the same time.

In this way, Terraform state is roughly analogous to Terraform's "backend database". When using Terraform in a team setting then, you'd typically select one of the [backends](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/) that stores state remotely and supports locking, and then anyone working with that particular Terraform configuration will find that Terraform will take out a lock before making any remote system modifications, hold that lock throughout its work, and then write the newly-updated state to the backend before releasing the lock.

Although you specifically asked about Subversion, my suggestions here are intended to apply to *all* version control systems. Version control is a good place to keep the source code for your Terraform modules, but it's not a good place to keep your Terraform state.